# Gulpfile - Copy node_module dist files into root directory

Tags: gulp

I am using .netcore mvc framework build would like to take advantage of other web stacks such as npm / typescript / gulp etc...

I would like to be able to specify the `node module/*/dist` files to copy into `wwwroot/lib` such that:

`node_modules/jquery/dist` gets copied into `wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist`

I will post my code below, however the problem is that my speified files get copied into `wwwroot` not `wwwroot\lib`

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var del = require('del');


gulp.task('lib', function () {
    gulp.src([
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*",
        "node_modules/jquery/dist/**/*",
        "node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/**/*",
        "node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/**/*",
        ],
        {
             base: "node_modules/*"
        }).pipe(gulp.dest('wwwroot/lib/'));
});
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (tested and working).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('lib', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/**/*',
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/**/*'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib'));
});
```